# Inserting Data to SQL Table safely and avoid sql insertion error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, odbc

MyI created a form that should gather information from data. This data may include random characters including " ' and so on. My question is how do I insert data safely without having sql injection attacks and where could i insert escape characters so that this form does not throw errors whenever a characters like ' "/ and so on are inserted.

Here is my code so far:

```
   public string InsertRecordSet()
    {        

        source = new FileInfo(@"c:\scripts\db_connection.txt");
        stream = source.OpenText();
        String text = stream.ReadLine();
        stream.Close();
        String uid = text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf(":"));
        String pw = text.Substring(text.IndexOf(":") + 1, (text.Length - uid.Length - 1));
        String connectionString = "dsn=" + "db" + "; uid=" + uid + "; pwd=" + pw + ";";
        String statement = "INSERT INTO table (SubmitDate, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, Major, Description, HearAbout) VALUES (@SubmitDate, @FirstName, @LastName, @Email, @Phone, @Major, @Description, @HearAbout)";                    

        conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);

        command = new OdbcCommand(statement, conn);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubmitDate", DateTime.Now);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFname.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLname.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Major", txtMajor.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Desciption", txtDescription.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HearAbout", txtMaxwell.Text);

        conn.Open();
        try
        {               
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return "true";
        }
        catch (OdbcException oe)
        {
            _dbError = true;
            Session.Contents.Add("USIFormException", oe);
            return (oe.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Injection protection, do not use inline SQL, but instead use parameterized SQL.

Parameterized SQL prevents SQL Injection, because it only allows values (or parameters) to be a part of the string, instead of anything. For example, you could not have `DROP TABLE xyz` in your parameterized SQL string, because the `Command` object knows that is not a legitimate parameter value.

So instead of this code:

```
String statement = "INSERT INTO MyTable(SubmitDate, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, Major, Description, HearAbout)";                    
statement += "VALUES (";
statement += "'" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "',";
statement += "'" + txtFname.Text + "', ";  

conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);

command = new OdbcCommand(statement, conn);
```

You should have code like this:

```
String statement = String statement = "INSERT INTO MyTable(SubmitDate, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, Major, Description, HearAbout) VALUES (@SubmitDate, @FirstName)";

command.Parameters.Add("@SubmitDate", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
command.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", txtFname.Text);
```

Note: Parameterized queries will not fully protect you against SQL Injection if your database logic is doing dynamic SQL, so avoid that too.

Comment: Well that solved the random injection problem, now the other problem is that whenever a user enters values like ' " and so on it throws a database error. any ideas on how to add escape characters or something to not have the errors being thrown?

Comment: when i did that now i get this error for some reason: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Must declare the variable '@SubmitDate'.

Comment: Not strictly true. Command object does not parse the contents for invalid SQL. Because parameters are passed separately, they can contain SQL & ', but because they are never parsed, this is not an issue.

Comment: You need to check the parameter syntax for your flavour of DB - MS SQL Server uses @paramname, Access uses ?.

Comment: oh Simon Im using SQL server 2000 for DB so i think it is the same

Answer (score 0):

You should use parameterized values.

```
string query =  "INSERT INTO MyTable(SubmitDate, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, Major, Description, HearAbout)";                    
query += " VALUES (@SubmitDate, @FirstName, @LastName, @EMail, @Phone, @Major, @Description, @HearAbout)";
conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
command = new OdbcCommand(query, conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubmitDate", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName",  txtFname.Tex);
...

conn.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcparametercollection.aspx

Comment: Well that solved the random injection problem, now the other problem is that whenever a user enters values like ' " and so on it throws a database error. any ideas on how to add escape characters or something to not have the errors being thrown?

Comment: when i did that now i get this error for some reason: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Must declare the variable '@SubmitDate'.

Comment: You have to add the Variables in your SQL Query too, as in the code above in the `VALUES(@SumbitDate, @FirstName, ...)`

Comment: I updated my code above to correspond to what I actually had when i got the error